(firestore.googleapis.com)] Uncaught exception in the SynchronizationContext. Panic
How to solve the uncaught exception in the synchronizationContext error while trying to add data to firestore
 val user:MutableMap<String,Any> = HashMap()
                    user["name"] = "kumudan"
                    user["email"] = "john.c.calhoun@examplepetstore.com"
                    user["password"] = "123456"
                    user["id"] = "1"
                    Firebase.firestore.collection("users").add(user)
                        .addOnCompleteListener{
                            if(it.isSuccessful){
                                Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: firebase data stored")
                            }
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener{
                            Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: ${it.message}")
                        }

Following Error is showing.
[Channel<1>: (firestore.googleapis.com)] Uncaught exception in the SynchronizationContext. Panic! (Ask Studio Bot)
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method acceptResolvedAddresses(Lio/grpc/LoadBalancer$ResolvedAddresses;)Z in class Lio/grpc/LoadBalancer; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.grpc.LoadBalancer' appears in /data/app/~~iInueUI_vMXJYVyXqpSaQg==/in.kumudan.aavinait-k0UDnbHCmNWoSQzpJOwGmA==/base.apk!classes18.dex)
   at io.grpc.internal.AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory$AutoConfiguredLoadBalancer.tryAcceptResolvedAddresses(AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory.java:142)
   at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener$1NamesResolved.run(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1848)
   at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:94)
   at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:126)
   at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener.onResult(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1862)
   at io.grpc.internal.RetryingNameResolver$RetryingListener.onResult(RetryingNameResolver.java:98)
   at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:333)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

I google for answer but i havent get any answers

What is the exact line of code that throws that error? Can you share it with us? Because as far as I can see, nothing from the shared code can throw such an exception.
